# Is restriction of outer measure to elementary sets giving elementary content always?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a question after reading about abstract measure construction in Folland's Real Analysis.

Definitions:

We have $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\phi,X \in \mathcal{E}$ and there is a map such that $\rho:\mathcal{E} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$(abstract 'content' over elementary sets).

Now we define $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $\mu^*(E) = \inf
\{ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \rho(E_n): E \subset \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} E_n,\ \text{and}\ E_n \in\mathcal{E}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
\}$

My question is simple:
Is it true in general that $\mu^* |_{\mathcal{E}} = \rho$?

I know it is true in the case of Lebesgue measure but it seems to me that such a thing requires some topological properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to establish.